# Import GeoTIFF data into ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geotiff-tiff, import

I have a problem with importing data to ArcMap. I want to import high-resolution temperature and precipitation data, stored in GeoTIFF files. Information about the project and the data can be found here: https://climatedataguide.ucar.edu/climate-data/chelsa-high-resolution-land-surface-temperature-and-precipitation

The files itself can be found downloaded here: http://chelsa-climate.org/downloads/

These are my settings for downloading the data. But I think my problem is with any GeoTIFF files. I think I don’t know exactly how to import them or use them.

[image]

When I download a file, I simply import it through “Add Data” and then select the file. I read ArcMap will automatically handle GeoTIFF correctly. After importing however, all I see is a blank map. The whole layer seems to be just white. I don’t know what to do with this layer and how I can access the information stored in it.

Maybe it’s not supposed to be imported as a layer in the first place? How can I make the data from the project visible in ArcMap?

[image]

Comment: Try changing the colours of the raster -- it may be that many of the values are at the higher end (near 65535) and thus are showing as white, or overlay on a non-white background.

Comment: Are you sure that you are looking at the correct coordinates? If not, "zoom to layer". Also, what happens if you use a different colour scheme (e.g. swap white and black)?

Comment: Does right click over layer name>Zoom to Layer option show it?

Comment: Thank you! Changing the colour scheme actually did help! Can you also maybe give me a quick hint, which tool to use to get the average value of specific region?

Comment: Calculate statistics for the raster